# How to get a warning that a class name is not recognized?

Tags: html, css, webstorm, atom-editor

Today I wrote the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="first">FIRST</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="first" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="second">SECOND</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="second" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="third">THIRD</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="third" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fourth">FOURTH</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="fourth" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The purpose of this code is to get a form that all of its element are in the **same line**. In order to make this happen, I used the class "form-inline", which is a part of Bootstrap directory. However, since I didn't loaded the Bootstrap files in the header, I got the elements in **separate lines**.

So I spent a lot of time to understand what is wrong with my file.
What I expect is that my browser/IDE gives an error for using an unknown class. Do you know how I can get this feature?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: What if (a real world example -- normal practice) class name is used for the future or for referencing this element via JavaScript or as data microformat markup ... and no styling is now or ever will be available -- why do I need to see errors in such case?

Comment: OK. So the word "warning" is better than "error". I want to get a warning for that, so I'll pay attention that I refer to a class that doesn't exist at present. What if I misspell an existing class name? Wouldn't you like to get a warning for it?